# How to build/deploy a node.js express in Netlify ? Without 404 error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, build, netlify

I developed a url shortener using node.js + express on the back end and react on the front end.

Locally it works normally, but when building on Netlify the project returns error 404 and does not work.

Is there any correct Build configuration for this type of project?

Below is the back end code

```
   const express = require('express');
   const shortid = require('shortid');
   const cors = require('cors');
   const { resolve } = require('url');
   const app = express();
   const PORT = 5000;
   require('dotenv').config();
   const urlDatabase = {};

   const corsOptions = {
      origin: '*',
      methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
      credentials: true,
      optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    };
    
   app.use(cors(corsOptions));

   app.use(express.json());

   app.post('/shorten', (req, res) => {
   const { originalUrl } = req.body;
   const shortCode = shortid.generate();
   const shortUrl = `${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/${shortCode}`;

   urlDatabase[shortCode] = originalUrl;

   res.json({ shortUrl });
   });

   app.get('/:shortCode', (req, res) => {
   const { shortCode } = req.params;
   const originalUrl = urlDatabase[shortCode];

   if (originalUrl) {
      res.redirect(originalUrl);
   } else {
      res.status(404).json({ error: 'URL not found' });
   }
   });

   app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server is running on '${process.env.BACKEND_URL}:${PORT}'`);
   });
```

And front-end

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Form, Button, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [originalUrl, setOriginalUrl] = useState('');
  const [shortenedUrl, setShortenedUrl] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const shortenUrl = async () => {
    try {
      if (!originalUrl) {
        setErrorMessage('Por favor, digite uma URL válida.');
        setShortenedUrl('');
      } else {
        console.log('Backend URL:', process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL);
        const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/shorten`, {
          originalUrl,
        });
        
        setShortenedUrl(response.data.shortUrl);
        setErrorMessage('');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error shortening URL:', error);
      setErrorMessage('Ocorreu um erro ao encurtar a URL. Tente novamente.');
      setShortenedUrl('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Encurtador de Link</h1>
      </div>
      <Form className='form'>
        <Form.Group controlId="formOriginalUrl" className='form-url-original'>
          <Form.Label className='text-url'>Insira o Link Original</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className='input'
            type="url"
            placeholder="Digite o Link original"
            value={originalUrl}
            onChange={(e) => setOriginalUrl(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" className='btn-url-original' onClick={shortenUrl}>
          Encurtar Link
        </Button>
      </Form>

      {errorMessage && <Alert variant="danger" className="mt-3 new-url">{errorMessage}</Alert>}

      {shortenedUrl && !errorMessage && (
        <div className="mt-3 new-url">
          <p>Seu Novo Link</p>
          <a href={shortenedUrl} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {shortenedUrl}
          </a>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The environment variable settings are correct.

However, when accessing the back-end url it returns nothing, so I believe the error is in the Netlify build configuration, could anyone help me?

Note: I'm a front-end dev and a back-end beginner

I've tried everything and I don't know what else to try

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this guide?  It explains all the likely reasons for unexpected 404's on Netlify including your likely culprit:  https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-i-ve-deployed-my-site-but-i-still-see-page-not-found/125

It's hard to be sure which is your situation without all the relevant details (for future reference: linking to your public build logs would have been ideal, so we could ensure that your deploy is actually succeeding and figure out what your function name is; it would also likely show whether you've already done what I am suggesting below with the rexdirect rule).

I'd suggest that the most likely of those reasons from the guide to be your proximate cause is #2 in the ordered list about making sure your app routes all traffic for which there isn't a specific file, to your router.  In the example, it talks about routing to `/index.html`, but I think you'll probably want to route to your function, whose path I am not certain of (it will be `/.netlify/functions/thenameyouchose`).  That looks something like this in an `_redirects` file:

```
/* /.netlify/functions/thatname 200
```

...or like this in a `netlify.toml` file:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/.netlify/functions/thatname"
  status = 200
  force = false
```

Note that in both cases, I assume that you might have other assets like `/logo.png` that you want to serve as static assets so I have not "forced" the redirect as discussed here in the netlify docs:  https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#force-redirects